# How to make input extend to width of column in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need my 2 inputs which placed inline to have width of parent div which defines `col-md-6` and `col-md-3`. Right now inputs are aligned correctly but have width which in one case less than `col-md-6` and in second case more than `col-md-3`. How to make this inputs have width `col-md-6` and `col-md-3` correspondingly?

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <form action="" role="form" class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="iR" class="sr-only">i R</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iR" placeholder="some mid long explanation" />
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="iS" class="sr-only">i S</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iS" placeholder="some mid long explanation 2" />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give `width:100%` for `.form-inline .form-control` and `.form-inline .form-group`.

Comment: Your `<form>` is not closed, it might help to close it properly first (just before your last `</div>`). Is your code properly wrapped in a `row` and a `container` as well ? Maybe add a link to a JSfiddle so we can see your code in action.

Comment: @anpsmn typically all you have to do is put width:100% for the input and if the parent class is the column then it will fill the column; no need for all of them.

Comment: @Blkc .form-group has `display:inline-block`so width to input won't affect the form-group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you need to specify custom widths with inline forms. [From the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline):

> Inputs and selects have width: 100%; applied by default in Bootstrap. Within inline forms, we reset that to width: auto; so multiple controls can reside on the same line. Depending on your layout, additional custom widths may be required.

In your case, you need to specify `width: 100%` for both the input and the form-group:

```
<div class="form-group" style="width: 100%">
```

and

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="iR" placeholder="some mid long explanation" style="width: 100%" />
```

[Working example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/060qmr7c/)

Answer (score 0):

Just put style="width: 100%;" on the input; Btw, you are missing a form closing tag.

Also if you look at bootstraps for any elements you set up most of the time they leave a bit of margins. So if you don't want any margins just change the margins to 0.